# How to check if date_start1 and date_end1 overlaps with date_start2 and date_end2 using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a database that  contains these columns:

```
event_start, event_end.
```

How do I check if `start` and `end`overlaps with event_start and event_end stored in the database. Here is my code I am using now:

```
public static bool IsAvailable(DateTime, start, DateTime, end)
{
    var query = from evnt in dbContext.events
                select evnt;
    foreach (var q in query)
    {
        if (start < q.event_end || end > q.event_start)
        {
            return false;
        }
    } 
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not enough that the start date is before the event end date - the end date has to be after the event start date too. Replace `||` with `&&`.

Also, you can replace the loop with a call to `Any()`:

```
return !dbContext.events.Any(q => start < q.event_end && end > q.event_start);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a Where to your query.

```
var data = dbContext.Events
    .Where(q => !(start < q.event_end || end > q.event_start))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this query to check is that any record clash with a specific range of date.

```
var query = (from evnt in dbContext.events
            where evnt.event_end >= start
            || evnt.event_start <= end 
            select evnt ).FirstOrDefault();

if(query != null){
    //it is overlap
}
```

If any record found by this query, there is at least one event overlap with your given date.

**Edited**
changed from `evnt.event_start >= end` to `<=` and `evnt.event_end <= start` to `>=`

Comment: I've tried this return query == null. but it always returns false.